# I want to load my own service provider rather than package's service provider

Tags: laravel

I have installed this package in laravel where I want to load my parts of code, changing a bit in the package's code
I tried to put it inside composer.json's dont-discover, this works in development and not in production.

```
extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
        "Yadahan\\AuthenticationLog\\AuthenticationLogServiceProvider"]
    }
  },

**I want to load my own code** 

In the appserviceprovider register() method,
if(!app() -> runningInConsole()) {
    $this -> app ->register(CustomAuthenticationLogServiceProvider::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define a binding to construct an alternate class using the service container: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container

Here's an example (*untested*):

```
public function register()
{
    if(!app()->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->app->bind(AuthenticationLogServiceProvider::class, function() {
            return app()->make(CustomAuthenticationLogServiceProvider::class);
        });
    }
}
```

So, every time your application code asks to construct `AuthenticationLogServiceProvider`, a new `CustomAuthenticationLogServiceProvider` will be given instead.